# Python gtts vlc plays too quickly to hear the first couple words

Tags: python, audio, vlc

In python, using the module gTTS and VLC-python, I've created a Text to speech program, which is quite simple to do.

But the thing which is bugging me is when I get to playing the mp3 file created by gTTS it skips the first word or two.

So if I have the string "The weather today will be cloudy". It'll speak out "today will be cloudy"

Even if I adjust the string, it seems to miss out the first word or two, sometimes it starts mid word.

When I play the audio file outside of the code, it plays normally, sometimes it stutters on the first word but if I rewind and have it wait a second, it plays perfectly.

Is there a way to load the audio clip or buffer it before playing so it starts smoothly?

Comment: vlc --no-playlist-autostart my.mp3

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are going to have something along the lines of:

```
self.Media = self.Instance.media_new_path('my.mp3')
self.player.set_media(self.Media)
self.player.set_xwindow(self.panel1.GetHandle())
```

which defines what is going to be played.

Then you will have something like:

```
if self.player.play() == -1:
    print("Error playing file")
else:
    pass
```

where you tell vlc to start playing the file.

put a `time.sleep(3)` before that play command or actuate the play function from a separate button or something.
This is the equivalent of the:
`vlc --no-playlist-autostart vp.mp3`
or
`vlc --start-paused vp.mp3` command line options.
i.e. load the file but don't start playing it, until I tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I found another library called `playsound` which plays the audio files back without any clipping:

```
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound

text = "Say something."
speech = gTTS(text = text, lang = 'en', slow = False)
mp3_file = 'text.mp3'
speech.save(mp3_file)
playsound(mp3_file)
```

I think this is a better solution than VLC, even if there was no clipping of audio in VLC, because using the `vlc` library requires you to have VLC Media Player installed on your computer, whereas this `playsound` library doesn't require you to install anything else for it to work.